# How can I submit a login-required app to the AppStore when I can't provide an account for test?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I know that an account for full access of all features is required when submit an app for review.
     Users of my app are in fact university teachers and students. Actually this app is just a third party one which I developed for iPhone users, for the reason that the original and official website of my university runs pretty bad and sometimes even fails on Safari. Obviously I don't have the access to the database to create a test account.
    In addition, the auth server is only open for users inside my university (the IP address of the server is a virtual one for local network.) Even though I provide them with my own account, they will still not be able to login.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Apple will not review a login-required app if they can't log in to it.

Comment: Is it possible when I made a virtual test account that doesn't directly send requests to server but pretend as if responses are received?

Comment: You'd probably pass review that way, but I suspect if Apple found out there was a difference between your fake account and a real one that they might pull the app.  Who knows how likely that is though.

Comment: So a better way is I set up a temporary server and make it work as the real one.

Comment: Yep, you could even code in to check for Apple's corporate IP address when the review team launches your app and just route them to your temporary 'dummy' server.

Answer (score 0):

Build a test server that interacts with the app exactly the same as the real client server except for being visible outside your clients secure network (and containing only a dummy data set, no actual private or proprietary data), create test accounts on that, test your app against that, then submit the app to Apple with a working test account on the test server.